# Arabic letter heh (ه) is rendered incorrectly when using the Calibri font

Tags: microsoft-word-2010, rendering, arabic

When I type the word `هذه` into Microsoft Word 2010 using the Calibri font version 6.18, the word is rendered like in `هذهذ` (without the trailing `ذ`), which means that the last letter has the incorrect form.

- Using any font other than Calibri works fine.
- Using any other application than Microsoft Word 2010 works fine. I tried LibreOffice, Microsoft WordPad, Google Chrome, Microsoft Word 2016.
- This also affects any text where `ه` appears as an isolated letter, such as in `ه` `ه` `ه` `ه`.

What could possibly lead to this situation?

Is there any way to trick Microsoft Word into rendering the word correctly?

Comment: Try adding a space after the last letter. Or any non letter

Comment: @Ayman I tried, but it didn't help.

Comment: Calibri [is not mentioned](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0647/fontsupport.htm) in the fonts that support the glyph; even more it seems [it supports no Arabic at all](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/font/calibri) (see also [missing characters](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/font/calibri/missing.htm)). So you're likely seeing another font. Still then, I guess it would be weird if Word uses a different fallback for Calibri than for any other font, and I'd even assume that Windows would take care of all this, so would work the same way in WordPad and all...

Comment: fileformat.info probably uses an old version of the Calibri font. The one I have says "(c) 2016 Microsoft Corporation. All Rights Reserved.", and I just looked into the font file using FontForge, which shows that the 2016 version contains Arabic characters.

Comment: Do you have Word 2010 and 2016 installed on the same system? And maybe the 2016 font uses some OpenType feature that the 2010 Word does not understand? And I guess it doesn't help, but [here you can show which local fonts render it](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/font/fontlist.htm?text=%D9%87+-+ARABIC+LETTER+HEH+%28U%2B0647%29).

Comment: No, at first I didn't have Word 2016 installed. And, as I said, the font information at fileformat.info is outdated.

Answer (score 2):

In the Unicode charts, I found [U+FBA6](http://unicode.org/charts/PDF/UFB50.pdf), which is the letter heh, isolated form. Now I have the word `هذﮦ` (the last letter is `U+FBA6`) from which I can use the letter via copy and paste.

The downside is that the above only works if the `ه` appears on its own, without vowels. Therefore rendering `هذه` works, but `هَذِهِ` doesn't. In the latter case, the vowel is placed too far to the left.

Comment: FWIW, this is a non-PDF reference for `U+FBA6`: https://www.unicodepedia.com/unicode/arabic-presentation-forms-a/fba6/arabic-letter-heh-goal-isolated-form/

Answer (score 0):

I have a solution for that ,if the letter `ه`.

After typing it appears, immediately press <kbd>shift</kbd> and <kbd>j</kbd> ( corresponds to (`-`) in Arabic)  and the result is `هـ`. I know tis because I’m an Arabic language user (English is my second language).

The characteristics of the letter `ه` in Arabic changes its form according to its place in a word, `هـ` is used when it is used in first place letter in a word while `ه` is used in last place letter in a word, hence the difference between `ه` and `هـ`.

Comment: Very good late answer/explanation!

Comment: The answer is correct in explaining that Arabic letters have different representations depending of whether they are at the beginning, in the middle, at the end of a word, or in isolated form. That's what I already know. My question was specifically about Microsoft Word 2010, since that program renders the word different from all other programs I tried.